# Understanding wildcard-constraint <? super T>

Tags: java, generics

I can work with basic generic expression but the wildcard-constraints just mess with my mind.

**Info:** Student extends Person and Person extends Animal

```
 List<? super Animal> aList= new ArrayList<>();

       // does not compile as expected, 
       // since the list is restricted to something that has Animal as superclass.
       // aList.add(new Object()); 

    aList.add(new Animal()); // I can add animal
    aList.add(new Person()); // I can add Person
    aList.add(new Student()); // I can add Student

    Animal a = new Animal();
    Animal b = new Animal();
    Person p = new Person();
    Student s = new Student();
    // test
    a = b; //I can assign an animal to another animal
    a = p; // I can assign a person to an animal
    a = s; // I can assign a student to an animal

    Animal animal = aList.get(0); // DOES NOT COMPILE, WHY ?
```

**QUESTION:** I don't understand why the last assignment does not work. The examples above show, that anything in that list is definitely an animal, yet I can't get an animal from that list.

**MORE SPECIFIC:** When I know that I can add only types which have Animal as superclass, why can't I expect to remove objects from type Animal ?

**FACT:** I can ONLY add objects which extend Animal! I just tried to add a car object and it does not work !

I am starting to doubt my sanity, I hope you can help me. Thank You

Additionally:

```
Object animal = aList.get(0); // works
```

Why does this statement work even though I know that I can't add an Object-Type ?

**SOLUTION:** (Based on the accepted answer)

I misunderstood the meaning of `<? super Animal>`

**What I thought it means:** Any class which has Animal as superclass.

**What it (apparently) means:** Any Class which is  superclass of Animal.

Therefore a List might also contain objects of type Object which is why `Animal animal = aList.get(0);` fails.

Cheers

Comment: I think you just want : List<Animal> in your aList declaration

Comment: What about `Animal animal = aList.get(1)` (with your example)? If you can answer that question, then you have the reason why it is not allowed.

Comment: I wan't to understand wildcard-restraints. Thank You

Comment: Are you sure that you are correctly differentiating `super` and `extends`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: `List<? super Animal>` does *not* mean: "something that has Animal as superclass", it means: some unknown type that is a superclass of `Animal`. So, it's the other way around than what you say in the comment.

Comment: Yes, but an object from a Class which does not extend animal can NOT be added to the list, so why can't i expect to at least get an Animal in return ?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose but a person is an animal so the assignment Animal animal = new Person() is allowed as stated in the tests.

Comment: My compiler disagrees.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Persons are humans,Humans are mammals, mammals are animals. or: (persons -> humans) && (humans -> mammals) && (mammals -> animals) <=> persons -> animals. (of course with the exceptions of those carved from a rip and made of clay.)

Comment: @vikingosegundo Now even I got confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`List<? super Animal> aList` is reference which can be used to handle `List<Animal>` ***, it can also be any superclass of Animal*** such as `List<Object>`.

In other words `List<? super Animal> aList`
 - is **not** reference to some list which can store **any** supertype of Animal.
 + it **is** reference to *list of some **specific type*** which is supertype of `Animal` (including Animal itself) but you don't know which type it is exactly.

So it could be

```
List<Object> someList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.add(new Car());//OK since Car is a Object
List<? super Animal> aList = someList;// OK since Object is supertype of Animal
```

Because of that, code

```
Animal a = aList.get(0);//and where did that Car come from?
```

is not safe. Only safe type to store the result of `get(0)` is `Object` so you either need

```
Object o = aList.get(0);
```

or if you want to make sure that `get` will return `Animal`, change the type of your `aList` reference to `List<Animal>` or even `List<? extends Animal>`.

Comment: I just tried it. If I create a class Car and try to add a Car to the list then it does not work. It is not compatible to <? super Animal>

Comment: @SklogW I added example showing how you can end up with wanting to place Car in Animal reference.

Comment: So this is needed simply because Java allows it to assign a restrained list to an obejct list ? It makes sense now why I might expect a Car-object but that java allows this is ridiculous.

Comment: What do you mean? Letting `List<? super Animal>` be reference to specific lists like `List<Animal>` or `List<LeavingThing>` or even `List<Object>` is entire purpose of `<? super Animal>` and because of that it would be unreasonable to simply assume that `List<LeavingThing>` or `List<Object>` will contain only `Animals`.

Answer (score 16):

The other answers here are right, but not stated clearly enough, which is where the confusion is coming from.

A `List<? extends Animal>` does *not* mean "A list of things that all extend Animal."  It means "A list of some type `T`, which I won't tell you what it is, but I know that `T` extends `Animal`."  (In type theory, these are called *existential types* -- there exists a type `T` for which our `List` is a `List<T>`, but we don't necessarily know what `T` is.)

The difference is important.  If you have "a list of things that all extend `Animal`", then it would be safe to add a Dog to the list -- but this is not what wildcards express.  A `List<? extends Animal>` means "List of something, where that something extends Animal".  It might be a `List<Animal>`, or a `List<Dog>`, or a `List<Cat>` -- we don't know.  So we have no reason to think that its safe to add a Dog to that list -- because maybe my List is a `List<Cat>`.

In your example, you have a `List<? super Animal>`.  This means, a list of some type T, where T is one of the supertypes of Animal.  It might be a `List<Object>`, or a `List<Animal>`, or if Animal has a supertype HasLegs, it might be a `List<HasLegs>`.  Here, it's safe to *put* a Dog into this list -- because whatever its a List of, Dog is definitely one of those (Animal, Object, etc), but when you take something *out* of the list, you have no idea whether its a Dog, an Animal, or just an Object.

Comment: I still don't understand why I can't add something of type Object to the list but on the other hand I can get it from the list ? I guess I am too stupid for this. It is like a bag of different colored marbles, I know i can't get the color right but I know that everything in there is at least spheric.

Comment: When you have a `List<? extends Animal>` (could be List<Animal>, List<Dog>, List<Cat>), you can _take animals out_, but you can't _put animals in_.  When you have a `List<? super Animal>` (could be List<Animal>, List<Object>), you can put animals in, but you can't take them out.  Only when you have an invariant list -- List<Animal> -- can you both take animals out and put them in.

Comment: @SklogW Probably because you're still interpreting the wildcard wrong.  `List<? extends Animal>` does not mean "A list of things, all of which extend Animal."  It is this common intuition that leads people into confusion; once you kick this intuition and realize what wildcards actually mean, it makes much more sense....

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

`List<? super Animal>` means a list of any superclass of `Animal`. If `Animal` is a subclass of `LivingThing`, then `List<? super Animal>` can be a list of `Animal`s, a list of `LivingThing`s, or a list of `Object`. In the last two cases, the assignment `Animal x = aList.get(0)` would of course be illegal, because you cannot assign a `LivingThing` to a reference of type `Animal`.

Consider the following method (it will not compile):

```
void f(List<? super Animal> list) {
    Animal a = list.get(0); // line 1
    list.add(new Object()); // line 2
}
```

The method call

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Object());
f(list);
```

is correct, because `Object` is a superclass of `Animal`. However, if the method `f` would compile, you would try to assign in Line 1 an `Object` to an `Animal` reference, so it would not be type safe.

On the other, hand consider the method call:

```
f(new List<Animal>());
```

If the method `f` would compile, we would now be adding an `Object` instance to a list which should only contain `Animal`s.

That's why both Line 1 and Line 2 are not allowed. If you have a class

```
public class A<T> {
    public put(T in) { } 
    public T get() { } 
}
```

then for the type `A<? super Animal>` the method `get` will return a `Object` (not an `Animal`), while the method `put` expects a parameter of type `Animal`.

Comment: Then why can't I add an object of a superclass of animal ? I can only add objects which have Animal as superclass.

Comment: @SklogW You cannot add an object of a superclass of `Animal` because it *could also be* a list of `Animal`s, to which you cannot add such objects.